# Unix permissions: remove/add file but do not change content

Tags: permissions

I would like to have the following set up:

A folder in which group users can remove/add files, but cannot change their content.

I was thinking:

> drwxrwxr--- (on folder)
>
> -rwxr-xr-- (on file)

Would this be correct? If so, how do I ensure that new files that are being delivered to that folder from a remote system have these file permissions in place?

Comment: Are you sure this makes sense?  If it's possible to remove and add files as you please, you could change the content by removing the file and then replacing with a file with the changed content.